# Calling a SQL Server stored procedure with linq service through c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I am new to Linq and trying to convert this SQL Server stored procedure into Linq, I am building a Silverlight business app and need to call on this procedure to return a grid of results.

I have multiple parameters that the users can use to search for particular pieces. They narrow down their search through the UI and when they hit the search button, the code behind takes all the arguments and sends it to my Linq service, which then needs to call on the stored procedure.

Here is the stored procedure.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spSearchResults
@PieceType      nvarchar(6) =  '',
@FileType       nvarchar(3) = '',
@Market     nvarchar(6) = '',
@PieceNumber        nvarchar(6) = '',
@Header1    nvarchar(50) = '',
@Header2    nvarchar(50) = '',
@Header3    nvarchar(50) = '',
@Header4    nvarchar(50) = '',
@JobNumber      nvarchar(50)=' ',
@bShowInActive  BIT = 0,
@UDAC1      nvarchar(50) = '',
@UDAC2      nvarchar(50) = '',
@UDAC3      nvarchar(50) = '',
@UDAC4      nvarchar(50) = ''   
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT J.* 
FROM Job J
  LEFT JOIN JobHeading H1 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] =  H1.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobHeading H2 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] =  H2.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobHeading H3 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] =  H3.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobHeading H4 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] =  H4.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobUDAC udac1 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] = udac1.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobUDAC udac2 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] = udac2.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobUDAC udac3 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] = udac3.[JobID]
  LEFT JOIN JobUDAC udac4 (NOLOCK) ON J.[JobNumber] = udac4.[JobID]
WHERE ((@PieceType = '') OR (PieceType = @PieceType))
  AND ((@FileType = '') OR (FileType = @FileType))
  AND ((@Market = '') OR (Market = @Market))
  AND ((@PieceNumber = '') OR (PieceNumber = @PieceNumber))
  AND ((@JobNumber = '') OR (JobNumber = @JobNumber))
  AND (J.IsActive=1 OR @bShowInActive = 1)
  AND (((@Header1 = '' AND @Header2 = '' AND @Header3 = '' AND @Header4 = '') OR 
        H1.HeadingRowID = @Header1)
    OR (--@Header2=0 OR 
        H2.HeadingRowID = @Header2 )
    OR (--@Header3=0 OR 
        H3.HeadingRowID = @Header3)
    OR (--@Header4=0 OR 
        H4.HeadingRowID = @Header4))
  AND (((@UDAC1 = '' AND @UDAC2 = '' AND @UDAC3 = '' AND @UDAC4 = '') OR 
        udac1.UDACRowID = @UDAC1)
    OR (--@Header2=0 OR 
        udac2.UDACRowID = @UDAC2 )
    OR (--@Header3=0 OR 
        udac3.UDACRowID = @UDAC3)
    OR (--@Header4=0 OR 
        udac4.UDACRowID = @UDAC4))
```

In Linq I found that there are certain conversions to do and this is my attempt.

```
var query = from j in Job
                    join JobHeading H1 in Job on headingRowID1 equals H1
                    join JobHeading H2 in Job on headingRowID2 equals H2
                    join JobHeading H3 in Job on headingRowID3 equals H3
                    join JobHeading H4 in Job on headingRowID4 equals H4
                    join JobUDAC udac1 in Job on udacRowID1 equals udac1
                    join JobUDAC udac2 in Job on udacRowID2 equals udac2
                    join JobUDAC udac3 in Job on udacRowID3 equals udac3
                    join JobUDAC udac4 in Job on udacRowID4 equals udac4
                    join PieceType in db on piece equals PieceType
                    join JobFileType in db on filetype equals JobFileType
                    join Book in db on market equals Book
                    join PieceNumber in db on pieceNumber equals PieceNumber
                    join JobNumber in db on jobNumber equals JobNumber
                    join Job in db on FindJobs equals db
                    where ((piece = string.Empty) || (PieceType = piece))
                      && ((filetype = string.Empty) || (JobFileType = filetype))
                      && ((market = string.Empty) || (Book = market))
                      && ((pieceNumber = string.Empty) || (PieceNumber = pieceNumber))
                      && ((jobNumber = string.Empty) || (JobNumber = jobNumber))
                      && (showInActive = true)
                      && ((((headingRowID1 = string.Empty) + (headingRowID2 = string.Empty) + (headingRowID3 = string.Empty) + (headingRowID4 = string.Empty)) ||
                            H1.HeadingRowID = headingRowID1)
                        || (H2.HeadingRowID = headingRowID2)
                        || (H3.HeadingRowID = headingRowID3)
                        || (H4.HeadingRowID = headingRowID4))
                      && ((((udacRowID1 = string.Empty) + (udacRowID2 = string.Empty) + (udacRowID3 = string.Empty) + (udacRowID4 = string.Empty)) ||
                            udac1.UDACRowID = udacRowID1)
                        || (udac2.UDACRowID = udacRowID2)
                        || (udac3.UDACRowID = udacRowID3)
                        || (udac4.UDACRowID = udacRowID4))
                    select j.Job;
        return query;
```

However, the beginning 'Job' has an error, and says 'could not find an implementation ... 'join' not found' Can anyone help translate? Or offer a better way to call the stored procedure with the code behind? Thanks

Comment: why not leave it as a stored procedure?

Comment: because we have a whole linq service set up already for everything else the app does, but regardless, how can i call the stored procedure then? My attempts have also failed.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx), you can actually call your procedures from the `DBContext`

Comment: in addition to not having to rewrite it in linq, your stored procedure will be faster if you leave it as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your store procedure to the entity context and call it as it were a method.

To accomplish this, you have to add the store procedure to the entity model. You don't say how  are you building the model or what version of EF you are using, but I assume you can just go ahead and update the model from the DB and add the store procedure.

Once you have the SP in the model you have to turn the SP into a Function Import. The way you do this is by navigating to the store procedure in the Model Browser, right click the SP icon and select "Add function import". Because you are returning a complex result set, I suggest you build a Complex Type, which you will use as the result type of the SP. To create a Complex Type in the Add Function Import dialog click the "Get Column Information" button. That will present the return values of your SP, so you can create a new Complex Type by clicking the "Create New Complex Type" button. Give it a name and click OK. Your function import is now under "Function Imports" in the Model Browser.

The way you call you function import method is:

```
var result = context.spSearchResults(Your list of parameters...);
```

This executes the SP, and "result" should give you a list of objects of the type of your complex type.

A couple of references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534438.aspx

Just to be complete: other way you can add a complex type is: in Model Browser navigate to "Complex Types", right click and select "Create Complex Type". There you have to define a complex type that has the same properties (names and types) of the result set of your SP. In the dialog box select Complex in the "Returns a Collection of",

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is working so far, just to clarify, my context is what again? And if i set it to my 'Job' the spSearchResults say it is undefined.

Comment: In var query = from j in Job, Job is your ObjectContext (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx), that is the object that provides the mechanisms to work with EF and your data store. Are you instantiating the context before using it?

Answer (score 0):

To call a stored procedure using linq just go to server explorer to connect with the database and then just select the Stored Procedures folder, and drag it to the dbml designer file. You will note that a method is added in the designer.
Then just instantiate the context and call your procedure.
example:
[Example Linq StoredProcedures](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1542/using-stored-procedures-with-linq-to-sql/)