# Error selecting from large data table causing time out in EF + code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I am using EF code first model to get the data from data base table in which i have 400,000 records.

But when i use the LINQ query something like:

```
var urer = context.UserEntity.Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains('s'));
```

The above statement gives me all the user to whose first name contains 's'. But since this is a huge data base table, it is giving me the following error:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Please suggest me the best way to do it. I am assigning this data to gridview. I am thinking to get the first 500 each time. Is there any way to do it from EF side, so that i won't need to do it in sql.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.add index on your column
2. increase timeout connection
You can create Store procedure 
USE LINQ call Store procedure

LINQ to SQL (Part 6 - Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures) 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

See this answer as well
[Calling a SQL Server stored procedure with linq service through c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439893/calling-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-linq-service-through-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

1. Get rid of EF
2. set key in web.config common key for timeout replace  600

   ```
   try
   {
    conn.Open();
    mySqlCommand.Connection = conn;
     mySqlCommand.CommandTimeout=600;
   ```

Comment: I can't simply get rid of EF. We have a system already built on EF.

Comment: Sorry, I am just very negative for EF just increase the timeout connection.